# How to remove the AWGN noise from data?

Tags: matlab, noise, noise-reduction

I have a vector `uo=[20 30 40 50];` I add white noise noise to it using `awgn`, i.e. `u=awgn(uo,30);`

Now I want to remove this noise from it and I want to get back my original vector `uo`. I did `uo=u-awgn(30)`, but it gives me an error. Can anyone guide me on how to get back my original vector exactly? But if it's not possible exactly, then can I get back my original vector *approximately*?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot recover the vector.

If you want a version with less noise you could save the original and then compute something like `(u + (uo - u)*noiseLevel)`, `noiseLevel=0` gives you `uo`. Putting it together

```matlab
uo=[20 30 40 50]
% u=awgn(uo,30); % assuming this will give you another vector like uo
u = u = [20.1132 30.0876 39.9573 50.0960]
noiseLevel=0.5;
u2 = (u + (uo - u)*noiseLevel)
```

```txt
u2 =

   20.057   30.044   39.979   50.048
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dear Bob for your kind response. That's good. Even if I can get my original vector having less noise, it is ok. But I didn't understand your expression. I am coding it in MATLAB. So if I want to re-write your solution statement, Will it like e this:

Comment: noiseLevel=30; Original= (u + (uo - u)*noiseLevel);

Comment: I tried it as below: clear all
clc
uo = [20 30 40 50];
u=awgn(uo,30)

noiseLevel=0;
Original=(u + (uo - u)*noiseLevel) but it gives me the Original having the same value as that of u. Then what's the need of this expression?

Comment: Noise level here is absolute (not dB) if you want zero noise you should simply use the `uo` value.

Comment: Thanks dear Bob for your kind response. I want different noise values such as 30, 40, 50 and 60. Let me reproduce above code with noise value of 30 i.e.,  clear all
clc

uo = [20 30 40 50];
u=awgn(uo,30)

noiseLevel=30;
Original=(u + (uo - u)*noiseLevel) When I run it , I get: u =

   19.9757   30.0117   39.9929   50.0353  and Original =

   20.7058   29.6594   40.2069   48.9753
You can see that your farmula gives much less precise answer.

Comment: Then you simply use `u20 = awgn(uo, 20); u30 = awgn(uo, 30)`, etc. you could also use a cell array or an array if you think that's better.

Comment: Thanks again dear Bob for your kind response. That's fine. But I am saying that the value of u20 or u30 etc. is more closer to uo than that given by your farmula. I mean your farmula gives a value which is very far away from my uo. But the value of u20 or u30 is closer to uo. So what's the advantage to use your famula then?

Comment: My formula uses the same noise, if you call awgn again it will produce another noise, the values of awgn are different each call, what is invariant is the distribution.

Comment: Thanks again dear Bob for your kind response. But I am not getting you. I am saying that my problem is that I want back my original vector approximately. So when I use your formula, it makes the vector much more different from original than awgn makes it. I mean awgn doesn't vary my original vector so much as your formula does. So your formula doesn't provide me my original vector approximately.

Comment: The 30 in the awgn function is the noise level in dB? maybe you want `noiseLevel=10.^(-30/20)` to convert from dB to linear. If you show the relevant results it may make a bit easier to understand what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind response dear Bob. Yes the noise inside awgn is in db. And when I run it, it givers me these results:  u =   20.1132   30.0876   39.9573   50.0960

BobResult =   16.7184   27.4603   41.2379   47.2168   but the original vector is uo = [20 30 40 50]

Comment: I posted in the answer what you should get, and it is definitely not what you are showing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind response dear Bob. In your code, you have kept u as fixed but its not so. AWGN is an additive white gaussian noise. Each time u varies as it adds a random noise to uo. I mean you cannot keep u as constant. So if we uncomment % u=awgn(uo,30); % assuming this will give you another vector like uo and comment u = [20.1132 30.0876 39.9573 50.0960] and run the code several times, you will see that u is different each time. Further, u is much closer to uo as compared to u2. You can check it yourself.